# Is Zend Framework 1.10.x compatible with PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, zend-framework, compatibility

I'm currently developing in (learning) ZF1.10. I also just set up a new development server using Ubuntu 10.04 which came with php 5.3
I know that ZF will start using php 5.3 functionality as of ZF2, but will ZF1.10 work fully and normally running on a php 5.3 machine or should I downgrade my php?

For example, my own legacy code has problems with php 5.3, not just because of deprecated function alerts, but apparently binding parameters in a mysqli query works differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been running ZF 1.10 with PHP 5.3 for a few months now with zero problems. The only problems I had to fix were lack of default Date/Time setting in php.ini and those pesky deprecation warnings that shipped with PHP 5.3.0 (but were late downgraded).

I also make heavy use of namespaces in my code now. You can easily import namespaces into your controllers or subclasses, but obviously have to fall back on global namespace when referencing Zend classes directly, or in cases where Zend expects you to use a naming conventions. Just remember to include the leading  backslash when referencing global classes from inside namespaced code:

```
// if inside a namespaced class, 
// not having a backslash will cause an error
$form = new \Zend_Form
```

Comment: I still have to learn about the namespaces, but one thing at a time. I have my hands full with Zend at the moment. :)
Thanks for the great info Bryan

Answer (score 1):

I'm told that ZF 1.10 works perfectly with PHP 5.3. They're just not taking advantage of the new features in this version.

You may run into a few issues now and then (I haven't, but you might) - but I suspect they'll be quickly picked up and fixed if you file a bug report.

Comment: That's great to hear and a real reassurance. I can't wait to use ZF2 and the full power of 5.3, but first I'll have to learn ZF 1.10 but it's going fast as I'm developing full time in Zend now. Cheers Stephen.